# What means conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

I have a question about log form in C.
I have defined the variable, which was shown as the below,

```
double **rx, rr00, perranking;

rx0 = dmatrix(1, PN, 1, M);
perranking = 0;
rr0 = dmatrix(1, PN, 1, M);

for (period = 1; period <= hp; period++) {
    if (rx0[i][j - period] != -99) {
        rr00 += rx0[i][j - period];
        perranking++;
        period++;
    }
    rr0[i][j] = rr00 - double (log(perranking));
}
```

But, the log form always show that “conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data”. So how do I adjust my coding, please? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a complete program that can be compiled, as small as possible.

Comment: This code is not C.

Comment: "*show that “conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data”.*" for which line please?

Comment: Please *at least* provide the definition for all variables involved! Also which type does `dmatrix()` return?

Answer (score 1):

double value very often will not fit in the integer type.

```
double x = 10e54;
int y = x;
```

If you are sure that it will fit just add the explicit cast to suppress the warning

```
 int y = (int)x;
```

Comment: Also, it's not just that the value could be too large or too small, but also `double y = 1.5; var x = y;`. Now x would be 1, losing the fractional part.

Comment: @ckuri it is logical, but the warning is about something else